# Why is this login prompt randomly appearing?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

Every so often, I see my Pi 4 1GB is displaying a login prompt, for no obvious reason. Here is an image:

[image]

The Pi is set to boot up around 7am (via a timer plug), display a web page all day, then shut down at around 10pm (via a cron job). It works for days without issue, then one day I will just walk past it and see this prompt. I have no idea why.

The following screensaver settings are set, but I don't think this is really relevant:

```
#@xscreensaver -no-splash
@xset s off
@xset noblank
@xset -dpms
```

I can't see any obvious errors in the log files, apart from some occassional reference to `Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts`. I don't know if that's relevant or not.

It's like the Pi is logging out the active user somehow, or locking the system. This login prompt isn't displayed at boot.

Comment: that could be caused by a faulty keyboard

Comment: There's no keyboard or input device connected.